# Sed: Replacing Date Format

Tags: linux, date, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file where there is a date string of **"2014-06-01T03:11:00Z "** in every line. I would like to replace that with **"2014-06-01 03:11Z "** using sed.

I've been trying to use this code but, it's failing me:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]T[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]Z/[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9] [0-9]:[0-9]Z/g' \
    /home/aaron/grads/data/metars/${YMD}/latest.metars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your digit sub-expressions only match a single digit, but the date contains 2 or 4 digits.  A simple version that would match dates is:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\)T\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\):[0-9]*Z/\1 \2Z/g' \
    /home/aaron/grads/data/metars/${YMD}/latest.metars
```

However, this matches zero or more digits at each position where digits are expected.  You really want to insist on the correct number of digits in each segment.  A more refined version is:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)T\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\):[0-9]\{2\}Z/\1 \2Z/g' \
    /home/aaron/grads/data/metars/${YMD}/latest.metars
```

And since your `sed` supports `-i` without specifying a back-up suffix (so it is probably GNU `sed`), you can probably abbreviate that to:

```
sed -r -i 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}Z/\1 \2Z/g' \
    /home/aaron/grads/data/metars/${YMD}/latest.metars
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this GNU sed command to replace all the lines which contains the date string with the string you mentioned,

```
sed -ri 's/^.*([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\w*([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(.)(.*)$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5\7/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa
jgklj 2014-06-01T03:11:00Z jhgkjhvk
blaf 2015-12-08T03:15:02Z bvcjghj

$ sed -r 's/^.*([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\w*([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(.)(.*)$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5\7/g' aa
2014-06-01 03:11Z
2015-12-08 03:15Z
```

For to replace date only and print all the other text as it is then run the below command.

```
sed -ri 's/^(.*)([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\w*([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(.)(.*)$/\1\2-\3-\5 \5:\6\8\9/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa
jgklj 2014-06-01T03:11:00Z jhgkjhvk
blaf 2015-12-08T03:15:02Z bvcjghj

$ sed -r 's/^(.*)([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\w*([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(.)(.*)$/\1\2-\3-\5 \5:\6\8\9/g' aa
jgklj 2014-06-03 03:11Z jhgkjhvk
blaf 2015-12-03 03:15Z bvcjghj
```

Comment: It's relatively unlikely to matter, but your regular expression will match a few (emphasis on 'few', and 'not very probable') strings that should not be matched.  It also uses more remembered segments than really necessary, though it will basically work.  I'm not sure about stripping the material before and after the date, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also

```
$-sed -r 's/^([^T]+).((.*):){1,2}.([^Z])/\1 \3/g'
```